# Quantization and Bohr's model

Tags: quantum-chemistry, energy, electrons, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-structure

According to quantization it's said that emitted or absorbed energy is quantized.

Then, when it's said in bohr's model an electron changes its orbit (Let's say it goes to a higher energy shell from $n=2$ to $n=3$) The energy difference between the orbits is $100~\mathrm{kJ}$.  Now, according to quantization is the $100~\mathrm{kJ}$ itself a quantum. Or the $100~\mathrm{kJ}$ will be absorbed in quantized way?

Comment: No not the energy you give as this is so large it has to be that for a  mole of atoms therefore the quantum of light (radiation) used to excite one atom is this amount divided by Avogadro's number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energy difference between $n=2$ and $n=3$ in Bohr's model is
\begin{equation}
\Delta E=13.6\ \mathrm{eV} \times \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{9}\right) = 1.88\ \mathrm{eV} = 3\times10^{-22}\ \mathrm{kJ} = 181.4\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}
\end{equation}
Thus, for this excitation to occur, a *single* energy quantum (photon) with an energy of $1.88\ \mathrm{eV} = 3\times10^{-22}\ \mathrm{kJ}$ is required.

The excitation does **not** happen if:

- the photon has more or less energy than $1.88\ \mathrm{eV}$ (The energy difference needs to be matched exactly!)
- the same amount energy is distributed over multiple photons (The energy needs to be provided by a single photon!)

As already has been pointed out, the $181.4\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$ itself is not a quantum, but one mole of quanta, where each quantum has $1.88\ \mathrm{eV} = 3\times10^{-22}\ \mathrm{kJ}$ of energy. As each atom can only absorb this energy once (assuming it does not relax back to $n=2$ by emitting the energy), to absorb so much energy will also require one mole of atoms.